# notmuch cli argument "sort=oldest-first" in .notmuch-config?

Tags: notmuch

Is it possible to add arguments [notmuch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Notmuch) takes to .notmuch-config file? Arguments like `--sort=oldest-first` would be really helpful if set by default to `notmuch search` command.

My workaround is to override it in .zshrc, by it would be great if there was support directly in notmuch project:

```
notmuch() {
    if [[ $1 == "search" ]]; then
      # remove "search" from "$@"
      shift 1
      command notmuch search --sort=oldest-first "$@"
    else
      command notmuch "$@"
    fi
}
```

I've tried `notmuch config set search.sort oldest-first`, but it didn't work.